# How can I run the macro in the spreadsheet (.xlsm) before the sheet will be used for another process?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a batch which will produce a spreadsheet , and a macro (vb script in it). This vb script should run before this file feed to the next batch for processing.  What would be an easier solution. Both of these batches are written in Java with Apache poi for spreadsheet handling. Will new File(filepath) with some parameter can open the file ? (So that I can place an Auto Open script in vbs which will execute it, I know its ugly )

Comment: Although you can extract macros in a limited way via POI, currently we can't write them to a Excel file - nor can we parse the macros and execute them. So "... run before this file feed to the next batch for processing ..." doesn't work within POI. Is there anything in this macro, which can't be programmed in Java? Does the resulting file - after those two batches - need to contain macros?

Comment: @kiwiwings As you suggested  ,  had incorporated the changes what macro doing into java as I figured out running the vbs scipt from Java /Unix script is quite complicated.